# Counterexample Isomorphic Homology groups implies isomorphic fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to find an example of two spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $H_k(X) \cong H_k(Y)$ for all $k$, but $\pi_1(X) \neq \pi_1(Y)$.

I've been dabbling with $S^n$.

Comment: The famous example is the [homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere).

Comment: If you look only at the fundamental group, $S^n$ won't give you such an example: $\pi_i (S^n) = 0$ for $i < n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example would be $X=T^2$ the torus and $Y=S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$.

Both of them have homologies $H_0 \cong \mathbb Z,H_1 \cong \mathbb Z^2,H_2 \cong \mathbb Z$ and the rest are $0$ (as can be seen by direct computation or by Kunneth and Mayer-Vietoris respectively.)

However, the fundamental groups are $\pi_1(T^2) \cong \mathbb Z^2$ and $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2) \cong \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$ (as can be seen using the fact that homotopy groups commute with products and Van Kampen respectively.)